# Quais são as vantagens de se trabalhar diretamente com stdin, stdout e stderr?

Tags: r, console

#### Existe alguma vantagem em termos de velocidade ou algum outro aspecto?

Mostra as conexões:

```
showConnections(all = TRUE)
```

Exemplos individuais:

```
stdin()
stdout()
stderr()
```

Comment: João, você poderia esclarecer um pouco mais a pergunta? Existe vantagem em relação a que, em quais circunstâncias?

Comment: Possuo um script em Python que envia ao R um JSON simplificado em uma linha o qual recebo por stdin, efetuo o que tiver que fazer e depois devolvo no mesmo formato pelo stdout.
Já tentei argumentar que poderia me enviar o JSON por outro modo mas insistem que esta forma é a melhor.

Comment: Então acho que seria interessante explicar este contexo na pergunta! Abs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para responder à sua pergunta, vamos entender qual é o seu problema e quais são as soluções alternativas. O seu problema é transferir dados entre dois processos, o R e o Python. Eis algumas soluções para este problema:

- Salvar os dados em arquivos que são acessados por ambos os processos. Acesso a disco é relativamente lento. Por outro lado, você não precisará reexecutar seus programas para gerar os dados uma vez que eles estejam gravados em disco.
- Usar [sockets de rede](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soquete_de_rede). Se os dois processos estiverem na mesma máquina, a comunicação é rápida. A vantagem é que seu código estará preparado para transferir dados entre os processos caso eles sejam colocados em máquinas diferentes.
- Usar stdin e stdout. Nesse caso só vai funcionar se os dois processos estiverem na mesma máquina. A comunicação é rápida. A vantagem é que o código para ler da entrada padrão e escrever na saída padrão é bem simples.